# MySQl Query: copy a column named 'C' from table2 to column 'C' in table1 without losing any other column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables table1 and table2. I have to copy a column named 'C' from table2 to column 'C' in table1 without losing any other column data. Both field data types are same. Can anybody give me a proper query how to do it.

Comment: is Table1 already containing the C column or should you add it first?

Comment: Please provide table structures (CREATE TABLE). Are there any PK, UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Table1 already contains the C column and you can Join by id:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col1 = t2.col2, t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

source: http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Davide, That's exactly what I wanted and It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot :)